# maven: parent-version

Tags: maven

I don't understand what is the parent version and for what it should be good?

We use svn in our team and when I did update for the project the last time I notcied that the parent version is changed:

local pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <groupId>bar</groupId>
        <version>0.42-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
```

svn pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <groupId>bar</groupId>
        <version>0.45-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

When does parent version change and for what it should be good?

Answer (score 0):

A parent POM contain settings that apply to all child modules. This may include declaring plugin settings or choosing dependency versions.

A parent POM is no different to any other Maven artifact. It can change and when it does the version number must increment. Typically you want to always be using the latest available version of your parent.

You can use the [Maven versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html) to help manage versions, including forcing an update to the latest available parent version.

Answer (score 0):

Parent pom and child pom come into picture if you have a multi-module project. For example like the below

```
/myapp
 |- pom.xml       --> parent pom
 |+ module1/      
     | - pom.xml  --> child pom
     | - src/
 |- module2/
```

There can be several such hierarchies. There are 2 ways to define this inheritance

1. Add a xml block in parent pom to tell it which are the dependent modules. OR
2. Add a xml block in a module to tell whose is it's parent. (This is your case)

This means that, the child pom is dependent on parent and will try to find the the concerned artifact with `0.45-SNAPSHOT` version. This version has changed probably due to a newer build of parent has taken place replacing the version.